# password validation regex java

Tags: java

```
public String checkStrength(String password) {
        String result = "";
        //int strength = 0;
        
        
      //If password contains both lower and uppercase characters, increase strength value.
        Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("(?=.*[a-z])");
        Pattern pl = Pattern.compile("(?=.*[A-Z])");
        Matcher ms = ps.matcher(password);
        Matcher ml = pl.matcher(password);
        
        //System.out.println(ms.matches());
        
        if(!ms.matches()) {
            //strength += 1;
            result += "lowercase letter not found\n";
        }
        
        if(!ml.matches()) {
            //strength += 1;
            result += "uppercase letter not found\n";
        }
        
        
      //If it has numbers and characters, increase strength value.
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])");
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(?=.*[0-9])");
        
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(password);
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(password);
        
        if(m1.matches() == false || m2.matches() == false) {
            //strength += 1;
            result += "number and character combo not found\n";
        }
        
        
      //If it has one special character, increase strength value.
        Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])");
        Matcher m3 = p3.matcher(password);
        
        if(!m3.matches()) {
            //strength += 1;
            result += "special character not found\n";
        }
        
        
      //check length of password
        if (password.length() < 8) {
            //strength += 1;
            result += "length must be minimum 8.\n";
        }
        
        
      //now check strength
//        if(strength < 2) {
//          //return "Weak";
//        }
        

        return result;
        
    }
```

i have used regex for password validation.
i am using servlet for this validation but there is some issue arising.
this method isnt working. it returns all the errors even if some conditions are satisfied.
help!
if anything else reqd i will add it just ask.

input -

```
valid
```

expected output -

```
uppercase letter not found
number and character combo not found
special character not found
length must be minimum 8.
```

actual output -

```
lowercase letter not found
uppercase letter not found
number and character combo not found
special character not found
length must be minimum 8.
```

Comment: For what input do you expect what output and what does happen instead specifically?

Comment: lets say i input 'valid' as password. it shouldnt display the error that lowercase letter not found but it still displays that error.

Comment: Wouldn't a better approach to this problem be rather than using `regex` to search the whole string multiple times, you do a simple for loop that checks all of these at once? This would also definitely make your program faster. The only hard part might be checking a num + char combo, but I think it would be possible to implement. (Unless you mean something completely different from num + char combo than I believe you do).

Comment: it isnt that complex project. i am just trying to make a password validator using regex. if u find any issues in the code pls tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern are incomplete. Add `.+` at the end of each pattern.

Example: change

```
Pattern.compile("(?=.*[a-z])");
Pattern.compile("(?=.*[A-Z])");
```

to

```
Pattern.compile("(?=.*[a-z]).+");
Pattern.compile("(?=.*[A-Z]).+");
```